# OpenCV Mat over network with VideoWriter is received plain green

Tags: python, opencv, udp, gstreamer, h.264

I want to send a simple video stream over network using OpenCV in python, and I am facing a weird issue where the output image will be green whatever the input is.
Here is a minimal program that reproduces the error:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

# Stream settings

FRAME_SIZE = (150, 150)
FPS = 30

# Network settings

HOST = '20.0.0.10'
PORT = 5000

# Create GStreamer pipeline string to send frames over network

pipeline_str = f'appsrc ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host={HOST} port={PORT}'

# Create VideoWriter object to send frames over network

out = cv2.VideoWriter(pipeline_str, 0, FPS, FRAME_SIZE, isColor=True)

# Generate test frame

frame = np.zeros((FRAME_SIZE[1], FRAME_SIZE[0], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
frame[:, :, :2] = 255  # Set plain cyan color

# Updating stream frame continuously

while True:
    out.write(frame)
    time.sleep(0.033)
```

The program runs just fine without any error. I use the `gst-launch-1.0` tool to receive the stream with the following pipeline :
`gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! queue ! "application/x-rtp" ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink`

The output looks like this:

[image: Decoded stream image]

No warning nor errors in both programs.

Sender:

- Jetson Nano 2GB
- Ubuntu 20.04
- OpenCV 4.1.1 with GStreamer support

Receiver:

- Windows 11 Laptop
- Intel i5 12500H
- NVidia RTX 3050 Laptop
- GStreamer 1.0 MSVC (complete install)

### What I already tried

- I verified the source frame is not actually green.
- I checked that I receive the stream UDP datagrams with wireshark.
- I tried to use OpenMAX hardware encoder (nvvidconv then omxh264enc) without success, no video was showing up at all (still no errors though).
- I tried to use jpeg instead of h264, shows a plain black picture with a few artifacts. Still no errors.
- I also tried many combination of caps to force the format, no success.

I thought it was related to OpenCV's BGR standard but the fact that just no format will work makes me scpetical about this.

Comment: why you don't try using a socket, here is a [useful tutorial](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/developing-a-live-video-streaming-application-using-socket-programming-with-python-6bc24e522f19)

Comment: That would work but my receiver must stick to a gstreamer pipeline, no code.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by increasing the `FRAME_SIZE`. It went out that (360x360) is the **minimum** that does not come out green.